# Narrowing conversion from double to float

Tags: c++, clang, tidy

This code has a clang-tidy error.

The error states: `Narrowing conversion from 'double' to 'float'` where it says x_pos inside the xPos(); function at the bottom.

Can someone explain why is that and how to correct it?

```
    //grab the current position
    double x_pos = clownfish->xPos();

    // move the fish 500pixels/sec in the right direction
    // delta time is measured in milliseconds, so divide by 1000 and multiply
    x_pos += 500 * (game_time.delta.count() / 1000.f);

    // update the position of the clown fish
    clownfish->xPos(x_pos);
```

Comment: Make the data type match.  Apperently `xPos` takes a `float`, but `x_pos` is a double meaning it can store values the `float` can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain why that is and how to correct it?

Narrowing:  Float is smaller than double, in a way analogous to int8_t is smaller than int16_t.  The biggest float is quite a bit smaller than the biggest double.

Note also: a smaller int will auto magically be promoted to a larger int.  Similarly, your compiler did not protest about "double x_pos = clownfish->xPos();", a double is always big enough to contain a float.

---

how to correct:

If you are confident that float (the smaller) is sufficient for your needs, or you are not allowed to change the clownfish code, then you might consider using a cast.

```
clownfish->xPos(static_cast<float>(x_pos)).
```

If you are willing and not prohibited from changing the clownfish code, ensure that the clownfish x position (i.e. what "clownfish->xPos()" returns) is a double, and that the function "clownfish->xPos()" returns a double.

Answer (score 0):

The warning message says what the problem is: ""Narrowing conversion from 'double' to 'float'". The [cpp core guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es46-avoid-lossy-narrowing-truncating-arithmetic-conversions) explain why this is potentially a problem.

Presumably, the `clownfish->xPos` function takes a float argument. Change the function to take a double instead to avoid losing precision. Or use float for `x_pos` so that there is no precision to lose. More generally, don't mix float and double willy-nilly.